# Select SUM then update in loop

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to make the sum of the column `FLAN01+FLAN02+FLAN03+FLAN04` and put the sum in flawtd for each flnumb. So I need your help on this, thanks

```
FLAID   FLCTRY  FLFY    FLLT    FLAPYC      FLAN01  FLAN02  FLAN03  FLAN04  FLAWTD  FLNUMB
2749023 20      17      AA      -2832227    0       0       0       0       0       1
2524    20      17      AA      -164999     0       0       0       0       0       2
2749023 20      17      AA      -2460920    0       0       0       0       0       3
2749023 20      17      AA      -2756040    0       0       0       0       0       4
2524    20      17      AA      -197730     0       0       0       0       0       5
2749277 20      17      AA      -133875     0       0       0       0       0       6
2749091 20      17      AA      -957654     -8619   -8619   -8620   -8619   -94812  7
2749091 20      17      AA      -957654     -8619   -8619   -8620   -8619   -94812  8
2749091 20      17      AA      -957654     -8619   -8619   -8620   -8619   -94812  9
2749091 20      17      AA      -957654     -8619   -8619   -8620   -8619   -94812  10
2749091 20      17      AA      -957654     -8619   -8619   -8620   -8619   -94812  11
2749091 20      17      AA      -921543     -9314   -9314   -9314   -9314   -102453 12
2749091 20      17      AA      -957654     -8619   -8619   -8620   -8619   -94812  13
2749091 20      17      AA      -921543     -9314   -9314   -9314   -9314   -102453 14
2749091 20      17      AA      -921543     -9314   -9314   -9314   -9314   -102453 15
```

Comment: Any query you attempted to write? Errors you found?

Comment: What do you mean by: put the sum in flawtd for each flnumb?

Comment: so basically you want to store sum in both columns?

Comment: yes getting error. i want to put the sum of fln01, fln02.... in flawtd with flnumb

Answer (score 0):

Try using an UPDATE operation like this:

```
UPDATE <table_name>
SET    FLAWTD = FLAN01+FLAN02+FLAN03+FLAN04
```

Database SQL Reference 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm

Comment: UPDATE F1202 SET  FLAWTD = FLAN01+FLAN02+FLAN03+FLAN04+FLAN05+FLAN06+FLAN07 WHERE FLFY=17 AND FLLT='AA' AND FLCHCD=2

Comment: Erreur commençant à la ligne: 3 de la commande -
UPDATE F1202 SET  FLAWTD = FLAN01+FLAN02+FLAN03+FLAN04+FLAN05+FLAN06+FLAN07 WHERE FLFY=17 AND FLLT='AA' AND FLCHCD=2
Rapport d'erreur -
Erreur SQL : ORA-01722: Nombre non valide
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number. I HAVE THIS ERROR

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the values making sure they are not null using [MySQL IFNULL function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/) for each non-null flnumb value.

```
UPDATE <table_name>
SET FLAWTD=IFNULL(FLAN01,0)+IFNULL(FLAN02,0)+IFNULL(FLAN03,0)+IFNULL(FLAN04,0)
WHERE flnumb IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I4AM USING ORACLE 11G DB